# Hexadecimal Role System

Tags: hex

I have this Roles & Hexnumbers:

```
0x1 - Employee |
0x2 - Pensioner |
0x4 - RoleOne |
0x10 - RoleTwo |
0x20 - RoleThree |
0x80 - RoleFour |
0x100 - RoleFive |
0x1000 - Administrator
```

Now I have the decimal number 4353 (Which stands for the roles employee,rolefive & administrator).

My question is with which technique can I get these roles out of my decimal number 4353  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of each of these "roles" as being represented by a specific bit, e.g. `Employee = 0x1 = bit 0`, `Pensioner = 0x2 = bit 1`, etc. So you can just use bitwise operators to test for each "role", e.g.

```
if ((person & Employee) != 0)
    // person has Employee bit set
if ((person & Pensioner) != 0)
    // person has Pensioner bit set
// ...
```

Note that this assumes C-like operators, where `&` signifies "bitwise AND". Your preferred programming language may have a different operator or even a function for performing this operation.